# Software to remotely change a user's password on a Solaris client

Tags: gui, remote-access, authentication, unix

I'm looking for software that will provide the ability to our helpdesk to remotely change a user's password on Oracle Solaris systems.

The Solaris systems use local /etc/passwd files (no LDAP/NIS etc). I could script a solution using Expect with a shell or Perl script, but if possible, we'd like to have a GUI based system that takes the client name, the user name and the password to change it to, before changing the password on that system.

I used a product called OpsWare many years ago which had this ability, but it no longer exists.

A solution that is lightweight rather than having all of the bells and whistles would be preferred as we really only need it to do this one task.